# Get a slide-up animation to work?

Tags: android

I want to animate a view sliding up and in. My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout "foo" is pinned to the bottom of my activity's layout. I'd like to have it initially hidden. For example, I'd like its top y coordinate to be the bottom pixel of the screen to start.

When I click a button elsewhere in the UI, I'd like foo to slide up, and end when its bottom edge touches the bottom of the screen.

When I click another button, I'd like foo to slide down, back to its original starting position (where its top edge is at the bottom pixel of the screen).

I'm trying to do that with the following animation definitions:

```
// slide up
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
  <translate
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">
  </translate>
</set>

// slide down
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
  <translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="700"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">
  </translate>
</set>
```

So my understanding - if I apply the slide-up animation, foo should reposition itself at -100% y, since fillBefore is true. It should then animate up to its original position, and stay there afterwards, since fillAfter is true. The slide down animation works similar.

But it's not working, the view seems to jump around. Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think everything you need is a SlidingDrawer class. It has some problems with wrap_content so you could use [WrappingSlidingDrawer](http://code.google.com/p/sw6android/source/browse/sw6.schedule/branches/prototype1/src/sw6/visualschedule/activitylist/WrappingSlidingDrawer.java?spec=svn1245&r=1170).

You should be able to hide the "handle" or just not doing it at all and slide the slider down and up with some other buttons.

Hope that helped :)

Comment: The problem with SlidingDrawer is that the animation duration is hard-coded into the class. Not sure why they did this. The animation turns out looking bad for my particular view. I ended up having to roll my own, ugh.

Comment: were you planning to share your implementation?